# rich:autocomplete ‘label’ and ‘value’ of suggestion list?

Tags: java, jsf, web-applications, richfaces, frontend

My target is that
View a suggestion list (bind by objects list in my controller)
Using `rich:autocomplete` component

A suggestion list items (objects) viewed as `userFirstName`, `userSecondName`
When select one item from the list
`The label` of the suggestion box need to be **userFirstName**
But
`The value` of this selected item that will pass to controller need to be **userId**

My issue is that
When I use this snippet

```
<rich:autocomplete                      
    autocompleteList="#{myController.myList}"
    var="var" 
    fetchValue="#{var.userFirstName}" 
    value="#{myController.id}"
    autofill="true" 
    layout="table" >

    <rich:column>
        #{var.userFirstName} 
    </rich:column>  
    <rich:column>
        #{var.userSecondName} 
    </rich:column>  

</rich:autocomplete>
```

The passed value to my controller is **userFirstName** not **userId**
The problem is that the value of `fetchValue property` is the both (`the label` and `the value`)
So how I can defer between `the label` and `the value` of the selected item?
Then i will able to view something in suggestion box and pass other to my controller

Comment: It most likely you want to do something like: `fetchValue="#{var.id}"` see if it works and I will add as an answer.

Comment: @JorgeCampos `fetchValue="#{var.id}"` is not my need because it will show `id` Not `userFirstName` in suggestion box after select any item of suggestion list

Comment: I wonder if a converter would help?

Comment: @Andrey May be but How?

Answer (score 3):

That's not actually possible, I'm afraid.

See [this post](https://community.jboss.org/thread/199113) for an example. The gist is that since `<rich:autocomplete>` is based on HTML's plain `<input type=text>`, you can only submit to JSF what has been entered in the text box (the value you define with `fetchValue`). The hidden state present in RF-3.3's autocomplete is gone.

People, myself included, have been cooking up custom solutions involving either hooking into the [rich:autocomplete#onselectitem](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_3_X/vdldoc/rich/autocomplete.html) client side event and writing the id to a `<h:inputHidden />` field or integrating a client side suggestion alternative like [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

I hear that the RF guys are going to revamp searching in RF-5, which is taking shape now.